# AngularJS $http.get within a $http.get

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I make a get call and retrieve some data that I want to use to make another get call and place that data within the `$scope`. Something like this.

```
$http.get('api/url/items').then(function(res){
  $scope.items = res.data;
  $http.get('api/url/names/' + res.data[0].id).then(function(res){
    console.log(res.data.name);
    $scope.name = res.data.name;
  }
}
```

The `$scope.items` is being populated but the `$scope.name` is not. The `console.log` gives the correct data but seemingly after the view as been rendered. How can I get the second `$http.get` to populate the within the `$scope` before rendering the view?

Answer (score 1):

Convert this

```
$http.get('api/url/names/res.data[0].id')
```

to this

```
$http.get('api/url/names/'+res.data[0].id)
```

Comment: Sorry that was a typo in the question, your response is how I have it in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I had two problems in my original code that was not in my simplified question that I now solved.

1. I was using a function to call the second $http.get. By the time that function callback came the original $http.get had already resolved so I moved that function code within the first $http.get.
2. I was using a for loop (var i) to both call the second $http.get function and set the value within my $scope.items[i]. By the time the $http.get resolved that i var already reached it's limit causing an undefined error. I created a counter var to change only within the second $http.get so the indexes match correctly.